# Preventing a p:dialog from updating whole page when using p:layoutUnit

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces

I've been using p:layoutUnit to create a basic menu. It works ok until I add a p:dialog component. In that case the whole page (including menu) reloads. I was wondering what is the best way to prevent this? I have created a minimal sample below and have also created a video to illustrate the problem here: http://youtu.be/aUFIBFnRQdA

The main page:

```
<h:head>    
    <title>Sample</title>   
 </h:head>
<h:body>

<p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:700px;">
<p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="false" size="300" minSize="40" maxSize="200">
    <h:form>   
    <p:menu>
        <p:submenu label="Menu">
            <p:menuitem value="Sample2" outcome="sample2" />
            <p:menuitem value="Sample3" outcome="sample3"/>
        </p:submenu>
    </p:menu>
</h:form>
</p:layoutUnit>

<p:layoutUnit position="center">
    <h3 style="margin-top:0">Plain Menu</h3>
    <ui:insert name="source2" />
</p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
</h:body>
```

The page with the primefaces command button:

```
<ui:composition
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  template="sample.xhtml">
<ui:define name="source2">
<h3 style="margin-top:0">PF Button</h3>
    <h:form>
    <p:commandButton value="Ajax Submit" id="ajax" styleClass="ui-priority-
primary" />
    </h:form>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The page with the primefaces dialog:

```
<ui:composition
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
  xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
  template="sample.xhtml">
<ui:define name="source2">
<h3 style="margin-top:0">PF Dialog</h3>
    <h:form>
        <p:dialog header="Sample Dialog" widgetVar="dialog" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false"/>
    </h:form>
</ui:define>       
</ui:composition>
```

Edit - Attempt at Ajax menu to resolve the problem (it failed - the whole page is still refreshed/updated).

```
<p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:700px;">
<p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="false" size="300" minSize="40" 
maxSize="200">
    <h:form>   
    <p:menu>
        <p:submenu label="Menu">
            <p:menuitem value="Stocks" actionListener="#
{menuView.selectStock}"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Portfolio" url="portfolio.xhtml"/>
        </p:submenu>
    </p:menu>
</h:form>
</p:layoutUnit>
```

With the backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class MenuView {

public void selectStock() {
    String outcome = "stocks.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();       
context.getApplication().getNavigationHandler().handleNavigation(context, 
null, outcome);
    }
}
```

Comment: You menu **always** updates the whole page simce you are using 'outcome' (and check the url bar). Maybe there is a visible issue when adding a dialog, but that is a different problem (if at all). Using ajax for the memu would solve this partially, see the PF showcase

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for the response. I've edited my answer with an attempted solution, although it seems the whole page is updated still. I'm not sure if the way I have implemented it is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on this post: [How to update a LayoutUnit in PrimeFaces to get it rendered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15615921/how-to-update-a-layoutunit-in-primefaces-to-get-it-rendered)

Now I update the menu option by returning the page url from the backing bean and then update the page using ajax which is wrapped in a panel.

So the index page looks like this:

```
<p:layout style="min-width:400px;min-height:700px;">
<p:layoutUnit position="west" resizable="false" size="300" minSize="40" 
maxSize="200">
    <h:form>   
    <p:menu>
        <p:submenu label="Menu">
            <p:menuitem value="Stocks" update="optionPanel" action="#
{menuView.selectStock}"/>
            <p:menuitem value="Portfolio" update="optionPanel" action="#
{menuView.selectPortfolio}"/>
        </p:submenu>
    </p:menu>
</h:form>
</p:layoutUnit>

<p:layoutUnit position="center" id="source">
    <h3 style="margin-top:0">Plain Menu</h3>
    <p:panel id="optionPanel">
    <ui:insert name="source">
    <ui:include src="#{menuView.view}" />
    </ui:insert>
    </p:panel>
    </p:layoutUnit>
</p:layout>
```

And the backing bean looks like this:

```
public class MenuView {

private String view;

public void selectStock() {
    setView("/stocks.xhtml");
}

public void selectPortfolio() {
    setView("/portfolio.xhtml");
}

public String getView() {
    return view;
}

public void setView(String view) {
    this.view = view;
}
```

For this to work I also had to remove the ui:composition and ui:define tags from the xhtml pages and re-instate them as standalone pages with head and body tags and standard headers.